# Android - Specifying custom theme for custom dialog AlertDialog.Builder wraps content within a dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I created a custom theme that inherits from 'Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog'.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="cust_dialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog"> 
</style>
</resources>
```

My code:

```
private AlertDialog testDialog;
AlertDialog.Builder testBuilder;
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_dialog,
                                   (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.test_root));
testBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.cust_dialog);
testBuilder.setView(layout);
testBuilder.setTitle("Support");
testDialog = testBuilder.create();
testDialog.show();
```

This causes my dialog to be within a dialog.  How do I fix this?

Thanks.

EDIT::::

This is my test_dialog.xml layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/test_root"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          >


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/test1"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp" 
            android:text="@string/test"

            android:gravity="center" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/test2"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="75dp" 
            android:text="@string/test"
            android:layout_below="@id/test1"
            android:gravity="center" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: maybe your `R.layout.test_dialog` contains more than just the content? `setView()`: "Set a custom view to be the contents of the Dialog". If you add a full Dialog layout there you end up with a dialog inside a dialog.

Comment: I have added my test_dialog layout xml.  I have nothing there but two buttons.

Comment: Should be caused by the root element you specify while inflating. Try with just `View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_dialog,null);` Otherwise you inflate the layout into itself.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't work.  Still showing a dialog within a dialog.

Answer (score 7):

try out this.

```
ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper( this, R.style.MyTheme );
            AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder( ctw );
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctw.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customdialogue,
                                           (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_root));
```

Comment: `ContextThemeWrapper ctw = new ContextThemeWrapper( this, R.style.MyTheme );
            AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder( ctw );` solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

It is very important to get the Inflater for the layout not through the usuall context, but via the context of the context wrapper... struggeled also a little bit at that point

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity, R.layout.test_dialog);
```